# JS does not work in google chrome and it only works on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

This the code I wrote in order to find the answer to a programming challenge and it's to insert  elements into a  element with the values equal to color names and choosing a color form the list will change the color of the  below it and it's supposed to be JS only. But my problem is that my code works perfectly on Firefox ,but it does not work in chrome or other browsers.

```js
const color = [
    "red",
    "black",
    "blue"
];

let select = document.getElementById("select");

for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    let container = document.createElement("option");
    container.innerText = color[i];
    container.value = color[i];
    container.id = i+1;
    select.append(container);
}

for (let j = 1; j <= color.length; j++) {
    select[j].addEventListener("click", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = `${select[j].value}`;
    });
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Test</title>
 </head>

 <body>
       <select name="" id="select">
       <option value="">Choose a color</option>
       </select>
       <div id="box">
       </div>
       <script src="script.js">
       </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you test it? Do you open the HTML file from your file explorer or do you serve it from a local server? If it's the former, some browsers disallow loading local JS.

Comment: Wow this seems interesting, When I opened this same browser and tested in edge it wasn't changing but in firefox it is changing

Comment: Should the first `select[j]` be `option[j]`?

Comment: I just tested it and you can't add event listener  (at least a "click") to option... Well you can, but it won't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well good news, **this isn't because of JavaScript is disabled on the browser**. I tried running your code against Firefox and Vivaldi and it seems that Vivaldi, Google Chrome, and other Chromium-based web browsers ignored your request to insert an event trigger. I mean this part of your code:

```js
for (let j = 1; j <= color.length; j++) {
    select[j].addEventListener("click", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = `${select[j].value}`;
    });
}
```

I don't know which one is correct: whether event triggers can be added inside the `<option>` tags inside a `<select>` or not. I might want to forward this issue to my team over [Webcompat.com](https://webcompat.com/).

Since you have already assigned the `value`s for each `<option>` (see `container.value = color[i];`), you don't actually need to add these event triggers for each of the `<option>`s. Instead, you can place the trigger directly inside the `<select>` element, replacing your second loop into this:

```js
select.addEventListener("click", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = select.value;
});
```

So the overall code would look like this:

```js
const color = [
    "red",
    "black",
    "blue"
];

let select = document.getElementById("select");

for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    let container = document.createElement("option");
    container.innerText = color[i];
    container.value = color[i];
    container.id = i+1;
    select.append(container);
}

for (let j = 1; j <= color.length; j++) {
    select[j].addEventListener("click", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = `${select[j].value}`;
    });
}

select.addEventListener("click", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = select.value;
});
```

**Edit:** using the `change` listener instead of `click` would be a better idea since the `colorChange()` function will only be executed if the dropdown value has been changed. Thanks to [pyb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223027/pyb) for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554695/3671760).

**Update:** I have forwarded this to https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/97662.

Comment: Tnx I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by making the following changes:

1. Use one `change` event listener on the select
2. Refer to the selected `option` element as `this`
3. Change `` `${select[j].value}` `` to `this.value` in the event listener

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Test</title>
 </head>

 <body>
       <select name="" id="select">
       <option value="">Choose a color</option>
       </select>
       <div id="box">
       </div>
       <script src="script.js">
       </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
const color = [
    "red",
    "black",
    "blue"
];

let select = document.getElementById("select");

for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    let container = document.createElement("option");
    container.innerText = color[i];
    container.value = color[i];
    container.id = i+1;
    select.append(container);
}

select.addEventListener("change", function colorChange() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});
```

Comment: It's working but can you describe why the former doesn't work in chrome and all chromium based browsers?

Comment: @prosach I suppose it has to do with browser compatibility. For instance I changed the following code (backticks are from the original question): `\`${select[j].value}\``.

Comment: The "click" works why is it better to use "change" instead? btw tnx for the help

Comment: "change" is also triggered when the selection was changed using a keyboard (focus the element with the tabulation key then changing the selection with the up and down arrows). It is [more accessible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554763/2223027) suggests there might be an issue with "click" in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

When the code works in a single browser ant not in the rest, it's an indicator that your code isn't written properly.
The fact that it runs in Firefox makes some sense, because this browser usually supports experimental options that are not yet supported globally.

Looking at your code, I found some issues, like declaring a function by name within event listener.
Setting a listener to an option element is counter productive in my opinion, so I changed it to a more standard/useful `change` listener.

```js
const color = [
    "red",
    "black",
    "blue"
];

let select = document.getElementById("select");

for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    let container = document.createElement("option");
    container.innerText = color[i];
    container.value = color[i];
    container.id = i+1;
    select.append(container);
}

// Select an option will trigger the change event.
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="">Choose a color</option>
</select>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with how event bubbling for select/option is implemented in Firefox and other browsers.

Try this simple code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("clicked")
}))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test</title>
 </head>

 <body>
       <select name="" id="select">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox logs that it's clicked, while Chrome doesn't.

Or try this code:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test</title>
 </head>

 <body>
       <select name="" id="select">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       </select>
</body>


</html>
```

Firefox reports that `option` was clicked, while Chrome reports that `select` was clicked.

Answer (score -2):

If this works properly in Firefox might be in chrome JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: there can be very more probable results than it. –